# Can someone give me an example of a function $f$ being analytic but its power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}$ diverging for some $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

is it necessarily true that $f$ being analytic implies its power series converges for all $x$? I think that it cannot diverge; however, I'm not very good at coming up with counterexamples. Can someone please help me? I believe that no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Analytic on the reals, not the complexes, right? Do you know anything with a finite radius of convergence (even if it's not defined on the reals)? Can you think of a function defined on all the reals where, when finding a power series, you would apply that thing with a finite radius of convergence?

Comment: yes, on the reals. i am thinking.

Comment: yeah i want one that's analytic on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is analytic for all complex values of $x$, then the power series will converge.  However if you mean analytic for all real values of $x$, then the power series will not converge if there is a singularity for some non-real (complex) value.  Simple example: $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ with power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because this is certainly the answer to the question, but if they were willing to put more thought into it with some guidance, then handing them an example sort of deprives them of some reinforcement/exercise of what they already know (whether or not they would find this standard example).

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Being analytic globally (i.e. $f\in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$) implies that a power series for $f$ centred at $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ for any $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ converges globally. On the other hand, a locally analytic function at $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ has only a local Taylor series approximation. That is, there exists some $R>0$ depending on $z_0$ so that $f$ has a power series 
$$ f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-z_0)^k$$
on $B_R(z_0)$. If we surpass this ball, the series may not converge. For example, take 
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}.$$
This function is analytic at $0$, with power series 
$$ f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$$
valid for $\lvert z\rvert<1$. Of course, at $z=1$, this diverges. You can repeat this sort of analysis on $\mathbb{R}$ with similar examples. For instance, $e^x$ has global power series
$$ e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!},$$ 
while the geometric series is only convergent within a radius of $1$ of the origin as in the complex case.

Comment: but doesn't $e^{x}$ converge for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Indeed,  but by contrast $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has a radius of convergent $R=1$.